# How to toggle active class on Foundation's section/accordion

Tags: zurb-foundation

Can anyone suggest a way to toggle the active class on foundation's section (accordion). I tried the following to collapse an open accordion tab:

```
$( "p.title" ).click(function() {
   if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
   $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
   }
});
```

However, it reverts back to the expanded state.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine. You only have to prevent the original foundation handler to handle the click after you handled it.

With your code the foundation handler gets called after your handler. It doesn't find the active tag anymore and adds it again. So your code should simply look like this:

```
$( "p.title" ).click(function() {
   if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
      return false; // Prevents further propagation of event
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

** Make sure it starts the accordion closed with one_up False,

data-section accordion ensures it will have the same behavior on all device.

The. problem whit the .click, is that it will not work on Ipads as the set state to hover before catching a click event.